# Can we call user defined scalar function into inline table valued function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can we call user defined scalar function into inline table valued function in SQL Server?

Comment: [Yes, obviously](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5b8f66d550388f33a6897fafab33d35b). But depending on your version of SQL Server, this may mean you inherit the performance problems inherent with scalar-valued functions that inline TVFs are typically used to circumvent.

Comment: Have you tried? And why would you want to anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. If you would like to make use of the performance benefits of inline table valued functions, it is probably better to have the scalar function reference the table valued function though, as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_tvf (
    @parameter_name AS INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (SELECT @parameter_name AS field);
GO

CREATE FUNCTION test_scf (
    @parameter_name AS INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (   SELECT tt.field
               FROM   dbo.test_tvf(@parameter_name) AS tt );
END;
GO

SELECT dbo.test_scf(123); --outputs 123
```

This would of course require a "TOP 1", or something to restrict the result set to a single row, in the table valued function to avoid errors where the function can produce multiple rows. In this example it just produces one row anyway, so it's not necessary. This code is obviously a bit of a mis-use of the table valued function, but since you asked :-D